# Cómo puedo cargar el contenido de una web a otra sin Iframes?

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy haciendo una web de **"streaming"**, pero no tengo idea de cómo poner en otro index el contenido del **stream**, no deseo que todo el mundo pueda hacer sus streams y quiero limitarlo solo algunas personas (eso lo tengo planeado hacer con un Login y autenticacion de usuarios para que me cargue las diferentes páginas. Por eso quiero la otra, una para emitir, que la llevara el admin, y otra para visualizar para los demas usuarios). Me parece que lo puedo hacer con **JS**, no estoy seguro. Me podrían dar una idea de cómo puedo hacerlo mejor?

Este es mi código:

```
!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html lang="es-MX">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
 </head>
 <body>

 <input type="button" id="button" value="INICIAR STREAMING" 
 class="buttonpro" >

   <div>
    <video id="video"></video>
   </div>

<script>
  var myButton = document.getElementById("button");
  var myVideo  = document.getElementById("video");

  myButton.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);    

  navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || 
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia || 
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || 
                         navigator.msGetUserMedia;

   function clickHandler(){
     if (myVideo.paused){
     getVideo();
   } else {
            myVideo.pause();
    myButton.value = "INICIAR STREAMING";
   }
   }

   function getVideo(){
      if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
      navigator.getUserMedia({
          video: true,
          audio: true
     }, onSuccess, onError);
     }
    };

   function onSuccess(streamVideo) {
   var videoProvider;

   if (window.URL) {
    videoProvider = window.URL.createObjectURL(streamVideo);
  } else {
    videoProvider = streamVideo;
 }

  myVideo.controls = true;
  myVideo.src = videoProvider;
  myVideo.play();

  myButton.value = "DETENER"
 }

  function onError(error) {
  console.log( error);
 }
 </script>  
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer lo así con jquery...

```
<body>
   <div id="streaming"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#streaming').load('pagina.php');
    });
</script>
```

obviamente despues tu lo decoras con css...

Answer (score 0):

lo puse asi dentro del body pero sigue sin cargar stream, no se si solo no se pueda o no esta cargando lo que tendria que cargar del script

```
   <div id="streaming"></div>

   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('streaming').load('index.html');
      });
    </script>
```